# string interning memory

Tags: c#, memory-management

where is a good resource on string interning . . how do i know if my app is a good candidate for string interning to help with memory footprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interning is done automatically by the runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx