# Practical use of Java String intern method

Tags: java, string

I know how ["intern" method of String works](https://dzone.com/articles/string-interning-what-why-and). But is there any practical / real life scenario where we will actually need to use intern method ? In that case is there any benefit of using intern over not using it ?

Or is it just a nice to have feature; only to be asked in interviews :)

Comment: [it´s still really abstract but might be a "real life" scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510425/real-life-practical-example-of-using-string-intern-in-java)